# Collision in 2D game

Tags: java, swing, collision

I'm trying to make a little game, where you have a little cube you can control with the arrows. When the cube intersects with another block object, I want it to go back and stop by the edge of the block object. So basically I want my block to stop when it intersects the block object, instead, it moves a bit in to it, and then when I move it again it jumps back. How can I make it so first checks if it will intersect, and if it will not move into it?

My drawing class extends `JPanel` and I'm painting with `paintComponent`.

```
 if(keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
        if(xRightCollision()){
            hero.x -= xVel;
        }
        else {
            hero.x += xVel;
        }
    }
```

So let's say the cube is at the edge of the block object, but it's not intersecting it yet, so I press right and it moves into it, I press right again and it jumps back 5 pixels(xVel = 5).

```
public boolean xRightCollision(){
    for(int i = 0; i < obstacles.size(); i++) {
        if (hero.intersects(obstacles.get(i))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've actually tried a similar thing with paint() on the `JFrame`, and since you have to call `repaint()` there, I could check first and then repaint. I don't really understand how `paintComponent` works since you can't control when it should be repainted.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a temporary value to check, if the cube intersects with an obstacle, and reset to the original position, if necessary:

```
if(keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
    //backup of the cubes position
    int tmp = hero.x;

    //move the hero to the right
    hero.x += xVel;

    if(xRightCollision())
        //cube intersects with an obstacle -> restore original position
        hero.x = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Right...thanks man, can't believe I didn't see that. Btw, if I would use paint() on a JFrame instead, it would not paint a new cube and remove the last one, but it would just add more cubes. But this doesn't happen in paintComponent, how come? Would you mind explaining that for me?

Comment: @Jullix993 strange, never had that issue. I'd have to see the complete code for this. Guess it's just some issue with your implementation of `paintComponent`.

Comment: Ok so here's a link to the game with paintComponent. The code is in a .txt file.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c297jqpngneln97/Code.txt?dl=0
I would really appreciate it if you could help me understand this.

Comment: @Jullix993 ok, now i see what you meant. i misunderstood the question. the reason why overriding `paint` will produce strange results is pretty simple: before a call to `paintComponent`, java will ensure that the area of the component is cleared. `paint` simply paints on the last screen without clearing before. you shouldn't override `paint` at all (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#swing_summary).

Comment: Ok, so I should always override paintComponent?

Comment: @Jullix993 exactly. if you want to paint, use `paintComponent`. always.